# How to setup JDBC connection configuration?

Tags: java, jdbc, jmeter, amazon-dynamodb, assertion

I setup JDBC connection config with this info:

```
database URL: jdbc:amazondynamodb:aws:dynamodb:region:account#
JDBC driver class: cdata.jdbc.amazondynamodb.jar
username:user
password:********
Connection properties
```

After that I set up JDBC request:

```
SELECT * FROM database name
```

Than when I run, in view result tree I get this error:

```
Cannot load JDBC driver class 'cdata.jdbc.amazondynamodb.jar'
```

I tried absolute path and relative path. Right now JDBC driver in placed in lib of jmeter with license file. Any ideas how to fix it?

Not sure if database URL is correct and what goes in connection properties?

Comment: A jar file is not a class name. They are 2 different things. And you may not even need to specify the driver class name at all, if the driver is capable of being automatically loaded.

Comment: Also, that URL looks suspicious. If you run the following at the command line `java -jar cdata.jdbc.amazondynamodb.jar`, then that (apparently) opens a GUI which lets you fill in all the data you need to provide, and then generates a valid URL for you - for example: `jdbc:amazondynamodb:Access Key=xxx;Secret Key=xxx;Domain=amazonaws.com;Region=OREGON;`.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter expects [fully qualified class name](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-fully-qualified-class-name-in-Java) of the JDBC Driver implementation, i.e.:

- `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` - for MySQL
- `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` - for Oracle
- etc.

So you need to use `cdata.jdbc.amazondynamodb.AmazonDynamoDBDriver` as the "JDBC driver class"

More information:

- [How to use Different JDBC Drivers](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732729-How-to-use-Different-JDBC-Drivers)
- [Use the CData JDBC Driver for Amazon DynamoDB in MicroStrategy Desktop](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/dynamodb-jdbc-microstrategy-desktop.rst)

Answer (score 0):

The driver class name looks wrong. It should be the actual class name of the driver, not the JAR file that contains it. For this driver, the class name should be "cdata.jdbc.amazondynamodb.AmazonDynamoDBDriver".

Answer (score -3):

1. ## JDBC CONNCETION IN SPRING BOOT PROJECT

   *****Step -1*****
   ----------------- First add Mysql/Oracle jar into your class path or add connectors in your POM.XML file.

   ### Step-2
2. open application.properties file.

   ---

```
add these field inside the properties file-->

spring.dbProductService.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.dbProductService.url =
jdbc:mysql://localhost:xxxx/<DataBaseName>

spring.dbProductService.username = xxxx

spring.dbProductService.password = xxxx
```

Comment: This question is not about Spring Boot, and in addition, please check how your answer is rendered before posting.

Comment: Your most recent edit did not improve things, nor did it address the fact that this question is not about Spring Boot.

Answer (score -3):

## Java with JDBC Connection

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //To load the driver
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/name","username","password");  //create the connection